# Multipy mutli parameters in Python

Tags: python

I am a begineer of python.

I want multipy multi arguements like this:

```
def multiply(*args):
    for nums in args
        return (args*args)

print(multiply(3, 4, 5))
60
```

EDIT:
Actualy i want to make one again for substraction

```
python    
minus(3, 4, 7)
    6
```

Comment: ``return`` exits a function (and therefore also your loop) immediately. Maybe you want to go through the official [Python tutorials](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) and learn the basics.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! [so] is a questions and answers site. You've posted what you want to achieve and code you tried. It's good to include both, but what is your question about them?

Comment: Also, are you looking into implementing such a function yourself, or do you just need its functionality for your software? If the latter, look into [`math.prod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.prod) in Python's standard library.

Comment: Actualy i want to make my own module :)

Comment: Subtraction in this context doesn't make sense.  Why is `minus(3,4,7)` equal to 6?  -3-4-7 would be -14.  3-4-7 would be -8.  How do you get 6?

Comment: My bad sorry. So.. we cannot make a multi substraction function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def multiply(*args):
    n = 1
    for nums in args:
        n *= nums
    return n

print(multiply(3, 4, 5))
60
```

You can do this in a single line using `functools.reduce` and `operator.mul`, but we'll leave that for a later lesson.

Comment: Maybe `multiply(start, *args)`? That way the 0-argument case can't happen (`1` is not an _objectionable_ return value for that case, but I have trouble seeing it or any other value as _correct_).

Comment: The zero-argument case works fine and produces 1.  I see your point, but I think the OP is still just learning all of this.

Comment: You are missing a colon after `args`, otherwise it will raise syntax error

Comment: @TimRoberts, ...yes, I'm well aware that the zero-argument case returns 1, but I don't see how/why that _or anything else_ is a correct value for it to return.

Comment: According to this wiki article, the conventional result of the product of an empty set is indeed 1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product

Comment: The sum of an empty set is 0, the product of an empty set is 1.

Comment: that article also reveals that `math.prod` effectively solves this problem (see my edited answer)

Answer (score 2):

You can use functools.reduce

```
from functools import reduce
def multiply(*args):
    return reduce(lambda a, b: a*b, args, 1)
```

edit:

It turns out there is something even simpler starting in python 3.8:

```
from math import prod
def multiply(*args):
    return prod(args)
```

Answer (score -1):

There you go

```
def multiply(*args):
    x = 1
    for e in args:
        x = x*e
    return x
```

Comment: Is there anything distinguishing this from the [other answer that preceded it by at least 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68491515/14122)?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, mine works, the other one raises error due to syntax error

Comment: Bluntly, a trivial typo/thinko that isn't specific to the OP's question doesn't strike me as a good reason to create a new answer (particularly, one with less explanatory text). More polite to just propose an edit to the preexisting answer).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you could have asked your question in more politely too, clearly I didn't see an answer was posted when I posted mine.